# How to prevent iframe from opening new links?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

### Backstory

I have some bandwidth problem so I currently want to iframe me good ol'site to new more bandwidth site without customer lost the golden bricks to my new site since the customers are really really old people so this is the best way.

### Code I use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color:yellow; height:100%">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web in a Web</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:orange; height:100%; width:100%"; min-height:100%; margin:0; padding:0>
 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

### Problem

Whenever I press one of the link in the left side, I was sent to the target site. However, when I press the link in the navigation, the page is still in the iframe.

newwebsite.com is opened in oldwebsite.com using iframe
whatever links users clicked in newwebsite.com, users must not redirected to newwebsite.com, users has to see oldwebsite.com in their browser.

I might not explain this well but I can make [an animated illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVnqS.gif)

## The Big Question

### How to prevent my new website from behaving the way w3school's sidebar behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I could see is:

Anchor points in the navigation bar are:

`<a href="/default.asp" class="topnav_home" title="Home">&nbsp;</a>`

Anchor points in the side navigation bar are:

`<a target="_top" href="default.asp" class="menu_default">JS HOME</a>`

This `target="_top"` part is making a problem because `_top` opens the linked document in the full body of the window.

Remove the target and it will work.

Comment: You are saying that I should not put any sort of target on links in my 'newsite.com' so that the iframe will stay there? Are there specific targets that may somehow 'touching' the iframe code? I am new too these, you may refer me to some article about how targets affect iframe!

Comment: Remove the targets from anchor points and it will work 100%. Tested. Or change targets to `target="_self"` or `target="_parent"` on your old website.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control external websites.
You can try to use target propritie but it prababily wont work!

Comment: I am not trying to control external websites, I am trying to prevent what this 'external website' did to my iframe.. I have my own 'external website' that I have 'control' of! Thx4Answering, m8! :v //I am asking how to make MY 'external site' not behave like the 'w3school site' .. Sorry to confuse you!

Comment: no problem so you may use it in all your links target='_blank' or target='_parent'

Answer (score 0):

### To prevent the website from behaving the way w3school's sidebar behaves I must do the following:

1. **Avoid Putting Target.**
   Some targets opens the linked document in a way that affects iframe.
2. **Change The Target.** If target is necessary, then, the target should be _self, _parent, and _top not working properly.